# jquery remove div and previous label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-manipulation

These are some input fields which i need to remove, but i am not able to remove the label tag

```
 <label class="prfx-row-title">Unique Selling Proposition </label>
 <div class="prfx-row-content">
     <input type="text" name="dynamic_usp[0][text]" placeholder="unique selling proposition " value="testing hello world" />
     <span class="remove button">Remove USP</span>
 </div>

$(".remove").live('click', function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
            $(this).parent().prev('label.prfx-row-title').remove();
        });
```

Now only the div is remove but not the label?

Anyone?

Comment: `live`...wow...blast from the past. (Note: `live` was deprecated years ago, and removed at least a year ago.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see `.live()` nearly every day when I visit SO :) It was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because when removing the `div`, it is no longer in the DOM, so the label is not a sibling anymore. remove the label first, then the `div`:

```
$(".remove").live('click', function() {
     $(this).parent().prev('label.prfx-row-title').remove();
     $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Or better :

```
$(".remove").live('click', function() {
     $(this).parent().prev('label.prfx-row-title').remove()
     .end().remove();
});
```

Comment: Tx Karl so simple yet i didn't see it. Your stitch solution looks like a winner ;)

Comment: It's the simplest thing that are usually harder to find ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can't remove `prev()` from something that is no longer there... so the easiest fix is just to rearrange the order...

```
$(".remove").live('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().prev('label.prfx-row-title').remove();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Also, if possible you might want to update the version of jquery you are using and use `on()` instead of `live()`. `live()` has been deprecated since 1.7 and removed since 1.9

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LpjkbLcn/)

---

You could also consider changing your DOM to something like...

```
<div class="prfx-row">
    <label class="prfx-row-title">Unique Selling Proposition</label>
    <div class="prfx-row-content">
        <input type="text" name="dynamic_usp[0][text]" placeholder="unique selling proposition " value="testing hello world" /><span class="remove button">Remove USP</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

and that way you could just do..

```
$(this).closest("prfx-row").remove();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LpjkbLcn/1/)

Comment: Superb! tx alreay gav Karl-Andre the accepted answer sorry

Comment: tx @smerny with the . $(this).closest(".prfx-row").remove(); your suggestion also works like a charm.

Comment: @alex yep and i feel it is a good practice to wrap content that belong together like that.